# Docker desktop automatically stopped on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

Recently I faced a problem that when I open docker desktop it's automatically stopped after a few seconds. I try to solve it in several ways like reinstalling the docker desktop and also trying some methods that are available on the internet as solutions. But these do not work for me.
Is anyone can help me, please.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have had lots of problems with installing `docker` on `windows` .
make sue you are following `docker`'s documentation step by step.

Most of the times the problem is related to wsl2 , hyper-v or cpu virtualization. check this parameters

[Docker in windows](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/)

Comment: Yes,I followed docker's official documentation to install docker

Comment: my problem is fixed

Comment: @RaselOfficial If you fix an issue please be so kind to share how you fixed it, or if it somehow just fixed itself. Instead of just writing that it is fixed. Thank you.

Comment: @Gaweringo  while installing docker in windows most of the times the problem is related to wsl2 , hyper-v or cpu virtualization. check this parameters

Comment: @MoeinMoeinnia For me the problem came up after using the updater in the docker desktop app. And it didn't really update properly. After updating docker desktop with `winget upgrade docker -i` it actually updated Docker and it now works.